# Why equals method in the String class defined as equals(Object anObject) but not as equals(String anObject)?

Tags: java, string, equals

this is `equals()` from `String` class

```
public boolean equals(Object anObject)
{
    if (this == anObject)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        if (anObject instanceof String)
        {
            String aString = (String) anObject;
            if (this.coder() == aString.coder())
            {
                return this.isLatin1() ? StringLatin1.equals(this.value, aString.value) : StringUTF16.equals(this.value, aString.value);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

1. So why it is defined as `equals(Object anObject)` but not as `equals(String anObject)`?
   What's the point of having an opportunity to receive any object if it's return false for any other objects than `String`?
2. If I create `MyOwnClass` should I override `equals()` method as
   `equals(Object obj)`
   or as
   `equals(MyOwnClass obj)`
   If as in the first option then why?

P.S.: covariance works in return type when overriding. I thought that if covariance works in return type when overriding so it must work in a function arguments too.

```
{
    public A foo(A o)
    {
        return new A();
    }
}

class B extends A
{
    @Override // everything OK
    public B foo(A o)
    {
        return new B();
    }
}
```

Comment: That is because `equals(String anObject)` does not *override* `Object`'s `equals` method, but instead *overload*s it.

Comment: Hint: Look at the source code for method `equals` in class `java.lang.String`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No answer so far gets to the heart of the issue.

Java's typing system is covariant (until you get to generics, where you choose which variance you want).

Given that `class Apple extends Fruit` and `class Fruit extends Object`, then **all Apples are also Fruits, all Fruits are also Objects, and all Apples are also Objects**.

And Object, because `java.lang.Object` says so, has an `equals(Object other)` method. That means that apples *must* also have this method:

1. All apples are objects.
2. All objects have an `equals(Object)` method
3. Therefore, apples have an `equals(Object)` method.

So why do objects have this method? Because it's useful. Because it makes `ArrayList`'s `contains(Object other)` method tick, it makes java.util.Set work. Once you've decided that all Objects have an `equals(Object other)` method, the rest (specifically, that apples have an `equals(Object other)` method, which trivially returns false if you ask it if it is equal to some non-apple object) is locked in; that is now the case simply because the system we've set up here (which is a covariant typing system, where the base type all types inherit from has an `equals(Object)` method) dictates it must be so.

Yes, the java language spec in fact guarantees it; you can't 'remove' the `equals(Object)` method from Apples. However, the crux of the matter is *why* the java spec works like this.

Comment: I thought that if covariance works in return type when overriding so it must work in a function arguments too.

Comment: Okay, let's say Apples only have `equals(String)`. Then: `Apple a = new Apple(); Object o = a; o.equals(new Pear());` - now what? how could the compiler possibly know that `o.equals(Pear)` does not exist? You can widen your param types. Not tighten them.

Comment: I mean parameters, not arguments (actual parameters)

Comment: @Denis_newbie the 'String x' in `public boolean equals(String x)` _is_ what I am talking about. the terms 'parameter' and 'argument' are ambiguous.

Answer (score 3):

> So why it is defined as equals(Object anObject) but not as
> equals(String anObject)?

`class String` overrides [`Object#equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) which has the following signature:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj)
```

In the case of overriding, the method signature (name and parameters) in the child class must be the same as in the superclass. If you change the number and/or type of the parameters, the method will be overloaded, not overridden.

> If I create MyOwnClass should I override equals() method as
> equals(Object obj) or as equals(MyOwnClass obj)

You should override it as

```
public boolean equals(Object obj)
```

otherwise, it won't be overridden; rather, it will be overloaded as mentioned above.

Answer (score 3):

> What's the point of having an opportunity to receive any object if it's return false for any other objects than String?

Given two `Object`s, you can legitimately ask if they are equal, even if the concrete types are, say, `Integer` and `String`.

```
Object first = 0;   // first is an Integer
Object second = ""; // second is a String

boolean equal = second.equals(first);
```

The `equals` method needs to accept the most general type.

> should I override equals() method as `equals(Object obj)` or as `equals(MyOwnClass obj)` If as in the first option then why?

The first. If you use the second way, it will only be invoked if both the receiver and parameter are of type `MyOwnClass` (as in, `receiver.equals(parameter)`). Otherwise, `equals(Object)` from `Object` will be invoked, because method overloading is resolved by the compiler, and `equals(Object)` is the only one the compiler knows that matches receiver and parameter.